# How to propagate css properties to inner Angular components and children?

Tags: css, angular

I have an Angular 2 app with custom HTML elements that looks like this:

```
<custom1>
 <div id="div1">
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <custom2>
   <div id="div3"></div>
  </custom2>
 </div>
</custom1>
```

In component *custom1* I have this css:

```
div {
 border-style: solid;
}
```

This style works well for the elements *div1* and *div2*, while it is not propagated to element *div3*.

How to propagate CSS properties of *custom1* into *custom2* without writing a specific CSS for *custom2* ?

In case it is relevant: *custom1* is included into a Bootstrap grid container.

Comment: any update on this ?

Comment: I didn't have the time to test your solutions yet. I hope I'll get some time this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) to None on your `custom1` component:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './custom1.component.html' ,
    styleUrls: ['./custom1.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

Snippet from the link I provided:

> Component CSS styles are encapsulated into the component's view and
> don't affect the rest of the application.
>
> To control how this encapsulation happens on a per component basis,
> you can set the view encapsulation mode in the component metadata.
> Choose from the following modes:
>
> **Native** view encapsulation uses the browser's native shadow DOM
> implementation (see Shadow DOM on the MDN site) to attach a shadow DOM
> to the component's host element, and then puts the component view
> inside that shadow DOM. The component's styles are included within the
> shadow DOM.
>
> **Emulated** view encapsulation (the default) emulates the
> behavior of shadow DOM by preprocessing (and renaming) the CSS code to
> effectively scope the CSS to the component's view. For details, see
> Appendix 1.
>
> **None** means that Angular does no view encapsulation.
> Angular adds the CSS to the global styles. The scoping rules,
> isolations, and protections discussed earlier don't apply. This is
> essentially the same as pasting the component's styles into the HTML.

Comment: Just as a reminder, this will not only propagate the styles to children components, this will propagate everywhere in your app.
To avoid this, you can add a class to the custom1 and add all other styles under it.
For example:
`<div class="custom1">...</div>`
Then, in your css file:
`.custom1 p { ... }`
This way, styles for p will only apply for tags under custom1 and its children.